# In need of a lightweight C++ Template Engine

Tags: c++, template-engine

I am in need of a very lightweight, fast, C++ template engine. I have been testing CTemplate and it fits my needs, yet it is a little slow. I have checked out many of the other template engines that have been recommended on this site, but most of them are more complex that CTemplate, and I am looking for the opposite. All I really need is simple text substitution, yet would prefer to use an existing engine. I also need a relaxed license, preferably MIT or BSD.

EDIT: Have looked into the following:
ClearSilver,
Teng,
Templatizer,
CTPP (This is a little complex to me... I pretty new to C++ and the linux dev environment)
qctemplate, and more, just have to try and remember them

Comment: What other templates did you try? You don't want people to repeat what you already tried.

Comment: What are the use cases? Embedded? Software development? Examples of what you want the engine to do?

Comment: Here's one: https://github.com/catnapgames/NLTemplate - very basic, single source file.

Comment: The term *templates* you are talking about is very different from the term *templates* most people think of in the context of C++. Perhaps you can state more clearly the kind of templates you are looking for in the question.

Comment: @TomA: NLTemplate looks good :-)

Comment: What is the requirement for "fast" here?  Are you generating C++ code, or something else?

Comment: The `NLTemplate` seems to be now located on https://github.com/monsieurgustav/NLTemplate.

Answer (score 6):

Created one, since I too dislike having boost as a dependency :-)

https://github.com/hughperkins/Jinja2CppLight

- uses Jinja2 syntax
- supports variable substitution, and for loop
- can be nested for-loops :-)
- zero dependencies, just c++ and standard libraries :-)

Comment: Do I understand correctly it depends on a local Python install?

Comment: Doesnt need python, doesnt use Python.  It implements a very lightweight version of Jinja2, in C++, for C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [syslandscape-tmpl](https://github.com/syslandscape/syslandscape/blob/master/doc/tmpl/README.md).

Project provide flexible and powerfull template engine for C++.

A tree-like data structre is used for storing template variables. Variables can be int, string, list or object.

**Features**

- variables
- for loops and nested for loops
- if and nested if
- include other templates

**Requirements**

C++11

**Template Storage**

Currently the engine supports only `string` and `file` storage for templates.

**Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <syslandscape/tmpl/data.h>
#include <syslandscape/tmpl/engine.h>
#include <syslandscape/tmpl/string_storage.h>

using syslandscape::tmpl::data;
using syslandscape::tmpl::engine;
using syslandscape::tmpl::storage;
using syslandscape::tmpl::string_storage;

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<string_storage> storage = std::make_shared<string_storage>();

  storage->put_template("/greetings.html", "Hello, I'm {$person.name}.");
  storage->put_template("/city.html", "I'm from {$person.city}.");
  storage->put_template("/age.html", "I'm {$person.age} years old.");
  storage->put_template("/examples.html", "\n{$message}: "
                        "{% for item in data %}{$item}{%endfor%}");
  storage->put_template("/index.html",
                        "{%include /greetings.html%} "
                        "{%include /city.html%} "
                        "{%include /age.html%} "
                        "{%include /examples.html%}");

  engine e;
  e.set_storage(storage);

  data model;
  model["person"]["name"] = "Alex";
  model["person"]["city"] = "Montana";
  model["person"]["age"] = 3;
  model["message"] = "List example";
  model["data"].append("Answer is");
  model["data"].append(" 42");


  std::cout << e.process("/index.html", model) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The link is dead and the project seems non-existing.